# What's pharse is common? "Just to entertain this ..." or "just for the sake of entertaining this ..."?

Tags: phrase-choice, colloquial-language

Which is more common? Or maybe they mean exactly the same so both are equally common?

Example sentence:

> **Just to entertain/just for the sake of entertaining** the fantasy of traveling to another country, he checked the prices of plane tickets
>   on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Just to entertain" is a lot more fluent than "for the sake of entertaining"**  ([You can see in Google Ngrams that "just to entertain" is much more common than "for the sake of entertaining"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just+to+entertain%2Ffor+the+sake+of+entertaining&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28just%20to%20entertain%20/%20for%20the%20sake%20of%20entertaining%29%3B%2Cc0)) **but neither one really sounds fluent or idiomatic.**

Both of them say that he's doing something *for the purpose of entertaining* the fantasy; that is, "for the purpose of giving consideration to".  That seems unnecessarily roundabout and wordy; he isn't checking ticket prices for the purpose of giving consideration to the fantasy, he's giving consideration to the fantasy *by* checking ticket prices.

I would just say "Entertaining the fantasy of traveling to another country, he..."